# SQL Stored Procedure Multidimensional query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two database tables LandGradingData and LandGradingImages. LandGradingData has a unique id column (called id) and LandGradingImages has a column called landGradingID which references the id column of LandGradingData

LandGradingData

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id | column a | column b |
+----+----------+----------+
|    |          |          |
+----+----------+----------+
|    |          |          |
+----+----------+----------+
|    |          |          |
+----+----------+----------+
```

LandGradingImages

```
+-----------------------+------------+---------------+
| LandingGradingImageID | ImageBytes | landGradingID |
+-----------------------+------------+---------------+
|                       |            |               |
+-----------------------+------------+---------------+
|                       |            |               |
+-----------------------+------------+---------------+
|                       |            |               |
+-----------------------+------------+---------------+
```

I have created a stored procedure that gets the data from LandGradingData, now I want to add in the LandGradingImages where landGradingID = id

This is where I am stuck, because LandGradingImages will return multiple rows where landGradingID = id, what would be the best way to return all the data from LandGradingData with the associated rows of LandGradingImages

This is what I got so far

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LandGradingProcedure]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @communityDesc varchar(255) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT id, columnA, columnB From LandGradingData
END
```

I will be calling this stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC and my .NET is expecting an array

```
public List<Reports> LandGradingReport(string community)
        {
            List<Reports> landGrading = new List<Reports>();

            try
            {
                using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("LandGradingProcedure", connection))
                    {
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        SqlParameter parameter1 = new SqlParameter("@communityDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                        parameter1.Value = community;
                        parameter1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                        command.Parameters.Add(parameter1);

                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Reports item = new Reports();

                                item.id = reader.GetValue(0);
                                item.columnA = reader.GetValue(1).ToString().Trim();
                                item.columnB = reader.GetValue(2).ToString().Trim();
                                item.images = reader.GetValue(3).ToString().ToArray();

                                landGrading.Add(item);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return landGrading;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Here is my class:

```
public class Reports
 {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string columnA { get; set; }
    public string columnB { get; set: }
    public char[] images { get; set; }
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this not work?

```
SELECT a.ID, a.ColumnA, a.ColumnB, b.LandingGradingImageID, b.ImageBytes
FROM LandGradingData a
INNER JOIN LandGradingImages b
on a.id = b.landGradingID
```

Comment: That could work, I would have to adjust my .NET code.....I guess I am looking for more of away to have the ImageBytes column as an array or object as there will be multiples.

Comment: it would probably be easier to manipulate it once you get it in .NET, then you would be able to do some LINQ query to just pull in the data from that ID that has multiple `ImageBytes`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.columnA,
       a.columnB,
       b.LandingGradingImageID,
       b.ImageBytes
  FROM LandGradingData  a
       LEFT JOIN LandGradingImages b ON b.landGradingID = a.id;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run. Also use the formatting tools so this legible. And sadly there are syntax errors here because you do not have the ON clause of your join.